# EF Core Include Between DateTimes

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET CORE with Entity Framework Core and I am trying to filter out result within a specific DATETIME frame.

This is my DBContext query:

```
var device = await _context.Devices.Where(d => d.Id == id)
            .Include(d => d.Layouts.Where(i => i.CreatedAt > fromDateTime && i.CreatedAt < toDateTime))
            .ThenInclude(a => a.States)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

'CreatedAt' is in 'datetime' format in the SQL Server, 'fromDateTime' and 'toDateTime' is also DateTime type.

The direct query is basically instant:

```
SELECT * [Id]
        ,[CreatedAt]
 FROM [Layout]
 Where CreatedAt > '2022-07-03 00:00:00'
 And CreatedAt < '2022-07-04 00:00:00'
```

But from the backend it takes very long, I did not wait until if finishes but more 20 minutes.

I would need help to find what I am doing wrong or how can I write the query to be faster.
Thank you.

Comment: Add `AsSplitQuery()`, you have Eager Loading with Cartesian Explosion of records. Also you SQL is not the same query, Eager Loading has no direct translation to the SQL.

Comment: The "direct query" you show here is not the same thing since it doesn't include any Device records. You could perhaps start with Layouts in your Linq query and go from there.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you that solved it! The split query is needed because there are multiple where statements (from and to datetime)?

Comment: No `AsSplitQuery()` is needed because you are loading with each device Layouts and States. Check [Split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add AsSplitQuery(), you have Eager Loading with Cartesian Explosion of records. Also you SQL is not the same query, Eager Loading has no direct translation to the SQL. –
> Svyatoslav Danyliv
> Jul 4 at 9:11

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).